# Problem installing Dream textures addon for blender: carson-katri.... Install dependencies locally?

Tags: python, github, blender

For a couple of days i've been trying to install the Dream textures addon in blender.

Github link https://github.com/carson-katri/dream-textures

I get the following error when i try to generate textures:

blender/3.2/scripts/addons/dream_textures/.python_dependencies/torch/lib/libtorch_global_deps.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory')

I think the problem is in the last part of the "contribute" part...

[contributing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvepT.png)

Install dependencies locally

```
Open Blender's preferences window
Enable Interface > Display > Developer Extras
Then install dependencies for development under Add-ons > Dream Textures > Development Tools
This will download all pip dependencies for the selected platform into .python_dependencies
```

After i click on "install dependencies"...5 hour and a dozen gigabytes later the .python_dependencies folder only has on file...gitignore..witch is empty?

I run blender as admin (from terminal) and open the directory as admin...but keep getting these at the end.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JhXh.png)

Since I only click on 'install dependencies...i can not add --upgrade etc to anything.

Can someone please tell me how to get these files in that directory....

thankss

MJ

Answer (score -1):

had same problem. Ran as administrator and disabled anti virus.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).